# Grid layout but avoid space distribute equally

Tags: css

I'm trying to use the grid layout for two columns in one row which can be easily achieved by flex. I have to create one more div for flex but the grid doesn't need one more div.

The problem with the grid is that it will divide the width space by 2 (cannot align to start/left) and that's not what I want, please refer to the first example below and you will understand.

Is there any way to use the grid in this situation but we can align the items to the left like in the second example?

```css
#main-1 {
  display: grid;
  gap: 30px;
  grid-teplate-column: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.test-1 {
  background-color: orange;
  grid-area: span 1 / span 2;
}

.test-2 {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 150px;
}

#main-2 {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.test-3 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
}

.test-4 {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 150px;
}

.test-1,
.test-2,
.test-3,
.test-4 {
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid</h1>

<div id="main-1">
  <div class="test-1"></div>
  <div class="test-2"></div>
  <div class="test-2"></div>
</div>

<h1 style="margin:30px 0 0 0;padding-top:15px;border-top: 3px solid #000;">Flex</h1>
<p style="margin:0 0 30px 0;">This is the desired layout but with one more extra div</p>

<div>
  <div class="test-3"></div>
  <div id="main-2">
    <div class="test-4"></div>
    <div class="test-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edited**

Inline-block might work but we cannot control how many items should be on each row. Imagine the width of the first div `.first` is dynamic and we do not know how wide it would be(but I will make it 30px for illustration). Now the desired layout should be only one `.first` and one `.second` on each row.

By `inline-block` it would appear that now each row is one `.first`, one `.second`, and one `.first`. Check out the example below. Because we cannot control the amount like grid on each row.

```css
#main {
  width: 120px;
}

.first,
.second {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
}

.first {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <p class="second">hhhhhh</p>
  <div class="first"></div>
  <p class="second">hhhhhh</p>
  <div class="first"></div>
  <p class="second">hhhhhh</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't believe so, that's what flexbox is for.

Comment: "No Way" to change the Grid Axis in this way. Imagine you work with table. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Grid_Axis.

Comment: Is there a reason for using either flex or grid here - as opposed to just making the children inline-block and the first child width 100%?

Comment: @AHaworth But we cannot control how many items should be in one row by `inline-block`

Comment: @AHaworth Let's say `div-1` is 30px and `div-2` is 60px and the container contains them is 120px. The first row would be `div-1 div-2 div-1` but the desired layout is `div-1 div-2` for each row.

Comment: I haven't undertood the generality of what you require. Why is the first div 30px and not 100% width?

Comment: @AHaworth I have made an extra explanation, please check out the new update of the question.

Comment: @Paulie_D Check out the answer below, you should believe it now.

Comment: It is not really a solution (You change the grid to 5 cols and use 2 of 5). But maybe for this specific case "Yes Way".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the columns as auto and keep only one at `1fr` then you can align to the left.

```css
#main-1 {
  display: grid;
  gap: 30px;
  /* update "5" based on your needs */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5,auto) 1fr;
  justify-content: left; /* align to left */
}

.test-1 {
  background-color: orange;
  grid-column: 1/-1; /* take all the columns */
}

.test-2 {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 150px;
}

#main-2 {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.test-3 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
}

.test-4 {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 150px;
}

.test-1,
.test-2,
.test-3,
.test-4 {
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid</h1>

<div id="main-1">
  <div class="test-1"></div>
  <div class="test-2"></div>
  <div class="test-2"></div>
</div>

<h1 style="margin:30px 0 0 0;padding-top:15px;border-top: 3px solid #000;">Flex</h1>
<p style="margin:0 0 30px 0;">This is the desired layout but with one more extra div</p>

<div>
  <div class="test-3"></div>
  <div id="main-2">
    <div class="test-4"></div>
    <div class="test-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```